# Timeline of Doctor Strange

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

Yesterday I watched [**Captain America: The Winter Soldier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier) and saw this scene.

[image]
Its around 1:15:25

So is [**Doctor Strange**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_(2016_film)) happened before **Captain America: The Winter Soldier**?? And when did **Doctor Strange** exactly took place?

Comment: try these links - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62872/when-is-doctor-strange-actually-set?rq=1, https://moviepilot.com/p/when-in-doctor-strange-set-mcu-continuity/4136034, https://screenrant.com/doctor-strange-mcu-timeline-year/ - but as the first concerns another answer from this site your question may ultimately be flagged as a duplicate. It is a good question though and somewhat of a noodle twister